# How to send HTTP post request which is stored/captured in RAW format using Python

Tags: python

How to send HTTP post request which is stored/captured in a file in RAW format using Python. I mean do we have any module already for it in existing api like: requests or urilib.request?

Comment: What do you mean by "RAW format"?  [The image format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format)?

Comment: No normal post request which contains all headers cookies and parameters which I captured and I just want to resend it using python

Comment: anyone who know about this? How to parse complete request in string/file to the request object